# How to keep Angular UI responsive during an http get request?

Tags: angularjs, http-get

I have a get request in my controller:

```
  $http.get('/api/ideas').success(function(ideas) {
    vm.ideas = ideas;
  });
```

As soon as my controller is called, this api is called, and my UI becomes unresponsive until i get the result from the callback / all ideas are listed (with mg-repeat obviously). When i have e.g. 1000 ideas in my database, my UI is unresponsive for 3-5 seconds. But i thought that call was a callback ?!

This is how my backend looks like:

```
    router.get('/api/ideas', controller.find);

    exports.find = function(req, res) {
      Idea.find(function (err, ideas) {
        if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        return res.json(200, ideas);
      });
    };
```

What is the problem here?

**EDIT - SOLVED:**

When i put a delay in backend like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Idea.find(function (err, ideas) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    setTimeout(function() {
      return res.json(200, ideas);
    }, 3000);
  });
};
```

although i just have 2 ideas, the UI is responsive during that 3 seconds. I can still click other parts till i get a response. So i think @Iggy is right. The problem is not the http get, but ng-repeat.

Comment: There's definite some missing variable here, the $http API uses XMLHttpRequest with async = true, so whatever your backend server is doing, your UI should still be responsive.  Are you using some kind of mocking framework that's changing the async call to sync?

Comment: I am actually having a mean stack app. of course there is a lot more behind the scenes, but i do not think that other parts are relevant for this issue.. Moreover we have just started with a default mean stack app. i don't think that those default parts may use an "async = false".. We really did not edit / manipulate too much logic in other parts

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Comment: That is not a solution. A tip to see the actual location of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the callback here (it's async), the problem is ng-repeat slowing your UI by adding your ideas one by one in the DOM.

To solve this you can use pagination, or look at the different way to improve ng-repeat performance.

A basic way to do so is to use the limitTo filter :

```
<div ng-init="totalDisplayed=20" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:totalDisplayed">
{{item}}
</div>
<button class="btn" ng-click="totalDisplayed = totalDisplayed+20">Load more</button>
```